# How to print highest score from this example?

Tags: python-3.x, max

I'm new to programming languages and learning Python. First of all, how do I learn the Python programming language effectively and faster?

Secondly, could you please help to run the program below? Any feedback will be highly appreciated. Cheers.

## Code

```
highest = 0
lowest = 0
results = []

result_f = open("results.txt")
for each_line in result_f:
 print(each_line)
 results += each_line
result_f.close()

results_as_float = map(float, results)
highest = max(results_as_float)
print("Highest score is : " , highest)
```

## Result:

5.0

7.5

6.75

4.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Study/Python/page116.py", line 16, in 
    highest = max(results_as_float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to first question depends how you learn best, different people learn  new concepts effectively and faster in different ways. But generally encountering problems like this one, and referring to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) to learn the python built-in library functions, then other third-party libraries, usually is the best way to learn python and other programming languages.

As for the problem, it originates from handling how python reads text-files. Everything is read as strings(`str` type). Then the errors begin from line `results += each_line`. You originally defined on line 3 `results` to be a `list`: `results = []`, but `results += each_line` performs concatenation onto the list using the strings from each line, including the punctuation and newline (`'\n'`) characters. so `results` eventually ends up looking like:

`results = ['5', '.', '0', '\n', '\n', '7', '.', '5', '\n', '\n', '6', '.', '7', '5', '\n', '\n', '4', '.', '0']`

which is probably not what you want in your list of `float` numbers. So to fix this, we need to clean each line python reads from the file and strip off the newline characters until we only have a list of numbers as "strings", then apply the `map()` function to that list:

```
highest = 0
lowest = 0
results = []

result_f = open("results.txt")
for each_line in result_f:
    print(each_line.strip())
    results.append(each_line.strip())
result_f.close()

results = filter(None, results)

results_as_float = map(float, results)

highest = max(results)
print("Highest score is : " , highest)
```

Will now print:

```
5.0

7.5

6.75

4.0
Highest score is :  7.5
```

Hope this helps.